# How to calculate the Gain of EDFA amplifier?

Tags: fiber-optics, optical-materials

I have co-propagating pump laser and tunable optical signal and I want to measure the Gain of [EDFA Amplifier](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=edfa+amplifier) from the Optical Spectrum Analyser (OSA). I have measured first the signal power without using the EDFA and then, the peak power and the average noise power after using the EDFA. Kindly direct me how to calculate the gain of the EDFA. Also, I have to calculate the spontaneous noise emission factor nsp from the data. I have all the values from the OSA such as resolution bandwidth, sensitivity etc.

Comment: Don't put in a link to a Google search. That's not helpful.